# How to set FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false in openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using openapi-generator-maven-plugin to generate Java files from the swagger yaml files. After conversion, the generated ObjectMapper is configured as FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES as true so the ObjectMapper will fail if receiving unknown properties.  Can I set additional tags in the pom file's plugin so the auto-generated FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES can be false instead of the default true?  The module is on Java 17/Spring3/openapi-generator-maven-plugin 6.6.0.

```
public class JSON implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {  
    public JSON() {
          mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
            .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .configure(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE, true)
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING)
            .enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING)
            .defaultDateFormat(new RFC3339DateFormat())
            .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .addModule(new JodaModule())
            .addModule(new JsonNullableModule())
            .build();
  }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath /> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bc.gov.open</groupId>
    <artifactId>jag-vips-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
    <name>jag-vips-client</name>
    <description>A java client for VIA database</description>

    <properties>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <!-- include properties that are specific to dpsvalidationservice -->
        <default-package>com.bc.gov.open.ordsviasclient</default-package>
        <maven-plugin-version>1.0.0</maven-plugin-version>
        <org.glassfish.jersey.version>3.1.5</org.glassfish.jersey.version>
        <com.fasterxml.jackson.version>2.15.2</com.fasterxml.jackson.version>
        <javax.xml.bind.version>2.3.1</javax.xml.bind.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>openshift</id>
            <distributionManagement>
                <snapshotRepository>
                    <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
                    <url>${env.NEXUS_SNAPSHOTS_URL}</url>
                </snapshotRepository>
                <repository>
                    <id>nexus-releases</id>
                    <url>${env.NEXUS_RELEASES_URL}</url>
                </repository>
            </distributionManagement>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${org.glassfish.jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${org.glassfish.jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${org.glassfish.jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${org.glassfish.jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
            <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Base64 encoding that works in both JVM and Android -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.brsanthu</groupId>
            <artifactId>migbase64</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.xml.bind.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>spring-boot-api</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/viasords.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>joda</dateLibrary>
                                <validateSpec>false</validateSpec>
                                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                            </configOptions>
                            <library>jersey2</library>
                            <apiPackage>${default-package}.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>${default-package}.api.model</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>${default-package}.api.handler</invokerPackage>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: There are so many things wrong in this pom file... using ancient old surefire/failsafeplugin version which do not support JUnit Jupiter as related to Spring Boot 3.1.X .. Why not using the version provided by Spring Boot? Joda Time?   Javax.xml.bind?? Old version of openapi maven plugin.. ?Manually binding the deploy plugin which is done by default... etc. Also the configuration for generator is wrong: https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java (using jersey2 while using jackson 2.15+ instead of 2.9 as stated in the docs... )...

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle it using `maven-antrun-plugin` like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <replace token="mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true)"
                             value="mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)"
                             dir="target/generated-sources/openapi">
                        <include name="**/our_generated_client/invoker/JSON.java"/>
                    </replace>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You can also `@Provide` a `contextResolver` which would change it on runtime

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperResolver() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> cls) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```